# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: android, stack-trace, indexoutofboundsexception

**StackTrace:**

```
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857): Process: com.loco.android, PID: 1857
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=4
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.sit.loco.frgment.VideoListFragment.onCreateView(VideoListFragment.java:117)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.sit.loco.activity.HomeActivity$2.onTabSelected(HomeActivity.java:117)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:577)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1105)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:547)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-19 08:47:02.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1857):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOFBoundException at runtime.I didn't know how to solve this error.

Error occurred at this line `YOUTUBE_USERNAME = ChannelUsername[position];`I mentioned that line in that VideoListFragment class.

**VideoListFragment.java:**

```
public class VideoListFragment extends Fragment {

OnVideoSelectedListener mCallback;

boolean loadingMore = false;

// create string variables
String YOUTUBE_USERNAME = "";

private String YOUTUBE_API = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+YOUTUBE_USERNAME+"/uploads?alt=jsonc" +
        "&v=2"+
        "&start-index=1"+
        "&max-results=10";

// create object of views
ListView list;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
Button btnRefresh;
Button btnLoadMore;

// create variable to get position, connection status, resources, and channel username
int position;
boolean isConnect = true;
Resources res;
String[] ChannelUsername;

// create object of custom adapter
VideoListAdapter vla;

// create arraylist variables
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

// flag for current page
int current_page = 1;
int previous_page;


static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_THUMBNAIL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";

// create interface listener
public interface OnVideoSelectedListener{
    public void onVideoSelected(String ID);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    // connect view objects and view id on xml
    list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    btnRefresh = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);


    menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // get value that passed from previous page
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    position = bundle.getInt("position", 0);


    // get channel username and put selected channel to youtube api
    res = getActivity().getResources();
    ChannelUsername = res.getStringArray(R.array.channel_username);
    YOUTUBE_USERNAME = ChannelUsername[position];----->Error occurred at line

    YOUTUBE_API = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+YOUTUBE_USERNAME+"/uploads?alt=jsonc" +
            "&v=2"+
            "&start-index=1"+
            "&max-results=10";

    // create LoadMore button
    btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());
    btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_default_holo_light);
    btnLoadMore.setText(getString(R.string.load_more));

    // adding load more button to lisview at bottom
    list.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

    new loadFirstListView().execute();

    // listener to handle load more buttton when clicked
    btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Starting a new async task
            isConnect = true;
//            new loadMoreListView().execute();
        }
    });


    // listener to handle list when clicked
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
            item = menuItems.get(position);

            mCallback.onVideoSelected(item.get("id"));

            list.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
    });

    // listener to handle refresh button when clicked
    btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            isConnect = true;
            new loadFirstListView().execute();
        }
    });


    return v;
}
}
```

**strings.xml:**

```
<string-array name="channel_name">
        <item >The Father House</item>

    </string-array>
    <string-array name="channel_username">
        <item >TheJesudian</item>

    </string-array>
```

Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: It's telling you that the length of your `Array` is only 1 but you are trying to find the 4th element. Figure out what each should *actually* be. You either don't have as many elements in your `Array` as you think or you are passing the wrong value. Probably the former otherwise you wouldn't need an `Array`.

Comment: ok what is the position value that activity received via bundle. `position = bundle.getInt("position", 0);`

Comment: @mmlooloo I don't know about that.But I need to add a one channel user name

Comment: @Naruto Shupident your `ChannelUsername` has just one element and so the position must be just 0, if you set it for example to 1 you get error.

Comment: @mmlooloo may be the error would be occurred at this for loop `for(int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++)`?

Comment: @Naruto Shupident No it is occurred at `VideoListFragment.java:117`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a position that array doesn't have. The int of the position is bigger than ChannelUsername size.