# Android - Cause: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException even with multidexEnable true

Tags: android, dex, android-multidex

**EDIT** : here is my full build scan : https://scans.gradle.com/s/fva2ntifaimgi

**Original Message :** 
I have the following issue that is not resolved event after adding `multidexEnabled true` to my `defaultConfig` in the gradle configuration of my app :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
...
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
...
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 65535
```

What is it that I have to check for the multidex to be truly enabled ? What am I doing wrong ?

My configuration is :

```
minSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 28
```

My Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="come.example.project">
<uses-permission [...]/>
<supports-screens [...]/>
<application
    android:name="com.example.project.App"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <!-- activities -->
[...]

    <!-- providers -->
[...]
    <!-- broadcast receivers -->
[...]
  </application>

</manifest>
```

My gradle configuration : 
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.project.dev"
    minSdkVersion 26
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      [...]
    }
    debug {
      [...]
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
      variant.outputs.all { output ->
        final String chain = [...]
        outputFileName = [...]
      }
    }
  }
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
  }
  dataBinding {
    enabled = true
  }
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE*'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    merge 'reference.conf'
  }
  externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
      path 'CMakeLists.txt'
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

greendao {
  // increment when changing DB structure
  schemaVersion 8
}

configurations {
  compile.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })

  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
  //implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'

  //implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'

  //implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:28.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0'

  //implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.0.1'

  //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

  //implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

  implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
  implementation('android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1-rc01') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
  }
  // logging
  implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
  implementation 'com.github.tony19:logback-android:1.1.1-12'
  implementation('com.papertrailapp:logback-syslog4j:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback'
  }

  // required for greendao encryption, disabled for now
  implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.6'
  // qr codes
  implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
  // events
  implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
  // http client
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

My Application file :

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
  }
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384004/arrayindexoutofboundexception)

Comment: Did you override multi dex in your application class?

Comment: I didn't. I tried doing it to see if it changed something but it didn't. Maybe I haven't followed the steps of overriding correctly ...

Answer (score 1):

You must do a few things.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?authuser=1

Add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Enable Gradle to know it's there

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

Override it in your application class if you have one:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
@Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Update your Manifest to point to your Application Class:

```
<application
      android:name="com.mypackage.MyApplication" >
      ...
</application>
```

OR if you don't have your own custom Application class that extends the Application class, then you can simply change your application tag to use the default support multidexapplication class and not worry about it.

```
 <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
 </application>
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try that and get back to you !

Comment: I edited one more thing for clarity, either you do a custom class and point to it, or you use the default class.

Comment: So my App that previously extends `Application` has now to extend `MultiDexApplication` ? or is it a new one that I have to reference ?

Comment: Yes, if you have a custom Application class, then it should override MultiDexApplication

Comment: You're still getting the same error? Post your manifest, your application file and your gradle. And confirm that you did File->Invalidate Cache and Restart after you ported to multi dex

Comment: I added the configuration file, the manifest and the gradle. You think it's coming from gradle configuration ?

Comment: hmmm. wondering if your variants are not pointing to the right application file. Try not using your custom application file and test that first. Simply use android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" > exactly as shown in your manifest and if that works, then you know you are not properly pointing to your application file in all variants.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate cache and restart android studio. go to file->Invalidate Caches/Restart